# How to handle a python object that could be sized or unsized

Tags: python, numpy

I want to write functions that accept a numerical parameter `x` that could be unsized, say `x = 1` or sized, a list, tuple or ndarray, say `x = np.array([1,2])`.  Is there a good way to write code that handles both cases?

As a concrete example, say the goal is to broadcast `x` into an array (of predefined shape `xshape`) if `x` is just a number and to return an error if `x` is an array with the wrong shape.

```
import numpy as np
import sys

if np.shape(np.atleast_1d(x)) == (1,):
    x = np.ones(xshape) * x
elif np.shape(x) != xshape:
    sys.exit("wrong shape for x")
```

The above code seems to work, aside from difficulties with nesting `x = [[2]]`.  It also seems to go against some recommended practices such as `try / except`.  Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Side note, the `<>` operator is deprecated, and gone in 3.x -- use `!=` instead.

Comment: is type(x) not sufficient?

Comment: @Radio I've seen `type(x)` advised against because there are too many cases and it goes against so-called "duck typing".  What I have seems to work if the unsized number is `float`, `int`, etc. and if the sized collection is a `ndarray`, `list` or `tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to do this is to defer to numpy, which handles all the various cases and hides the complexity from you. For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> xshape = (2,)
>>> np.ones(xshape) * 1
array([ 1.,  1.])
>>> np.ones(xshape) * [9, 8]
array([ 9.,  8.])
>>> np.ones(xshape) * [[9, 8]]
array([[ 9.,  8.]])
>>> # Wrong shape
>>> np.ones(xshape) * [[9, 8, 7]]
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-dd8a3b87c22c> in <module>()
----> 1 np.ones(xshape) * [[9, 8, 7]]

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2) (1,3)
```

Another related approach is to use `x = np.aarray(x)` at the beginning of your function/script. If `x` is already an array, nothing happens, but if `x` is a scalar or a sequence, an array of the appropriate shape is created and then you can write the rest of your code knowing that `x` is an array (if `x` cannot be converted to an array an error will be raised).